# I can't create a new Web Application using CA or PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I can't describe this problem but it happened after I restore a site collection from our development machine to the production server. I see the same error page also when I try to access the site collection.
I tried to set customErrors to Off on all web.config files on the server but no luck.
I deleted the Site collection and the web application of that site but nothing changed. other site collections are working just fine.

Please help.

This is what I see when trying to create a new Web Application.
[image: This is what I see when trying to create a new Web Application.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe One reason is There is already a web application with the same name or same port in Central Application ,

Confirm that that is not the case?

You can try to follow steps given below:

**Go to Central Admin->System Settings->Mange Service on server**

Check `status` of following service:

**Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application**

**If it is stuck at stopping state, follow the steps given below:**

**Open command Prompt**

Navigate to 14 Hive/Bin path

**Enter following command**

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype spwebservice
```

**perform IISRESET with "Noforce" attribute**

**Execute following command**

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice
```

**Perform IISRESEt with "Noforce" attribute**

Hope this helps

Comment: The service was started but I executed the stop/start commands that you gave me anyway and it's working now and I can create a new web application. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hope to hear that it helped you